# Why does scipy.interpolate not print interpolated values in scatter plot?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I am trying to use scipy linear interpolation to fill gaps in my data so that I can draw a scatter plot of my data.
I also want to print the values changed by linear interpolation, but I am not sure at all how to go about this.

My code does not seem to interpolate at all - the graph it produces has the same gaps as in the original data. When I run my interpolation function f6 for my missing data points, it returns nan just as before. I will paste my code below. (My data goes from 5 minutes to 1440 minutes with 5-minute intervals).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
node_6 = prob_1.iloc[:,1]

t= np.arange(5,1441,5)
f6 = interpolate.interp1d(t,node_6,kind='linear')
xli = np.linspace(5,1440,10000)
y_6 = f6(xli)
plt.scatter(xli, y_6, c='r', s=1)
plt.show()
```

[Screenshot of the graph this code produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yavU2.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer - My excel data had missing values which were coming through to python as nans. I needed to remove these nans before interpolating for the interpolation to work.